# Как в pm2 выполнять shell скрипты?

Tags: pm2

Я использую pm2, чтобы поднимать не только nodejs приложения, а поэтому хочу в качестве `script` вводить обычную shell команду, прямо в консоли, но такой конфиг у меня вызывает ошибки.

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: "_bot",
    script: "poetry run python main.py",
    interpreter: "/usr/bin/bash",
    cwd: "/root/pyt__bot/app"
  },
  {
    name: "_lavalink",
    script: "java -jar Lavalink.jar",
    interpreter: "/usr/bin/bash",
    cwd: "/root/pyt__bot/app/ll"
  }]
}
```

Как такое правильно сделать?